# Recordtype and Pagelayout

Tags: visualforce, tasks, activities, console, custom-console-components

I have 5-6 record types for our custom tasks with custom fields.

The current scenario lets people to choose the record type and then it redirects to another page with all the fields associated to that particular record type.

Is it possible to have the record type in the same page layout of the task? If so, how can i accomplish it?

Also, is there a way to get the visualforce source for the custom tasks what I have created with declarative configuration, so that I can modify the page the way I want to?

Answer (score 3):

Answering your two questions:

> Is it possible to have the record type in the same page layout of the
>   task? If so, how can i accomplish it?

No, by standard way, it first asks for RecordType then proceed to layout.

> Also, is there a way to get the visualforce source for the custom
>   tasks what I have created with declarative configuration, so that I
>   can modify the page the way I want to?

Yes, you can use this app to generate source code. [Visualforce Code Generator](https://visualforce-generator.herokuapp.com/). Some information on [how we can use it](http://dieffrei.com/en_US/salesforce-visualforce-code-generator/#more-227).

Comment: Is there no documentation for that tool? Might be better to link to documentation rather than the installer.

Comment: Neat little tool...

Comment: @AdrianLarson I couldn't find the documentation for it. But I know this is simple to use, having minimum required feature to figure out. Added some link if it could help.

Comment: @ashwani, it looks like i cant generate the code for the custom objects which we have made it in our org.